# Why redis-benchmark performance is different with real app benchmarking

Tags: node.js, redis, benchmarking, ioredis

```
redis-benchmark -n 1000000 -t set -q -c 1
```

The above benchmark provides the 19k request per second

But my Nodejs Benchmarking for 'set' command provides only 10k request per second

**So why the redis-benchmark have the 19k request per second as compared to my nodejs app 10k request per second?**

```
const Redis = require("ioredis");
const {
    performance
} = require('perf_hooks');

// Ready the Redis client A
const RedisAClient = new Redis({ host: "127.0.0.1", port: 6379 });

// Call our benchmarking
Benchmarking();


// Our benchmarking function
async function Benchmarking() {

    // Sleep async function
    function sleep(ms) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
    }


    const loopNumbers = 10000;
    let processedTasks = 0;
    const WholeTime = performance.now();

    for (let i = 0; i < loopNumbers; i++) {

        // Call redis for set command
         RedisAClient.set("testing", i, function (err, reply) {

            processedTasks++;
        });

        // If it is last loop then log the benchmark
        if (i == loopNumbers - 1) {

            // Wait for the all tasks to complete
            while (processedTasks != (loopNumbers)) { await sleep(1); }

            console.log((performance.now() - WholeTime) + "ms")

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Node will have some overhead the benchmarking tool may not. Are you benchmarking Redis or your benchmarking code? Node will never be as fast as C, but it can come close. Seeing it half as fast isn't all that surprising.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I am benchmarking Redis because I want to know that how much request the Redis server can handle per second. So can I believe in the 'redis-benchmark'? Means that benchmark tool give the right info about how much requestes the redis server can handle per second?

As my nodejs is giving about half, so if I point another nodejs process to the redis then both combine server will give the 19k requests per second?

My main concern is about the redis server.

Comment: Have you tried running more than one copy of your testing tool concurrently? `xargs` with the `-P` option is handy for this sort of thing. You will probably have to test something other than hammering the same command a billion times. Real-world conditions are often much stranger.

Comment: Yes, as my benchmarking function is async so I called it 2 time which runs at parallel. It did not have any effect.

As for the -P it is pipeline which send the bulk commands at once. It is not usefully as I am trying to know that how much request the redis server can handle per second for the simple call.

Comment: It is very crucial for me to know the redis server capacity so I will be able to know when I have to scaleup the redis. Again thank you for helping. Any solid way to benchmark the redis server for real world case using third party software or my simple nodejs benchmarking code giving the half performance as compared to redis benchmark tool.